# Ajax call to a controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am passing some data(check-boxes, strings) from my view to the controller using HttpPost.
Along with that data I also need to pass the value of 2 drop-down-lists that is selected by the user, these 2 are not bound with the model , they are just there in view.how to do it?

In view ->

Load Month :
            
                Jan
                Feb
                Mar
                April
                May
                June
                July
                Aug
                Sept
                Oct
                Nov
                Dec

```
    <div id="loadyear">
        Load Year :
        <select name="years" class="YearDropDown">
            <option value="2012">2012</option>
            <option value="2013">2013</option>
            <option value="2014">2014</option>
        </select>
    </div>
```

I have this along with other items that are bound to the model . When I use form-begin and HttpPost methods , I am able to retrieve them from the controller but how to pass loadmonth , and loadyear dropdowns so That I can see their value in the controller?

Comment: Please provide some code snippet from what you have tried so far.

Comment: I thiok this will be done by an AJAX call , but I don't know how to pass this via an AJAX call to the controller

Answer (score 0):

Please try this change for instance. I believe it will work.

you can set up a strongly typed hidden field for the drop down. On drop down change event put its value in hidden field. Rest the model and controller will handle. You need a little bit javascript/jQuery. I always prefer [jQuery](http://jquery.com/).

**Note:** your hidden field must be strongly bind with a property in model you are using in view.

#### Model

```
public class MyModel
{
   // your other stuff

   public string DropDownValue { get; set; }
}
```

#### View

```
<div id="loadyear">
    Load Year :
    <select name="years" class="YearDropDown">
        <option value="2012">2012</option>
        <option value="2013">2013</option>
        <option value="2014">2014</option>
    </select>
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.DropDownValue) 
</div>
```

#### Script

```
$(function(){
   $('#loadyear select').change(function(){
       $('#DropDownValue').val($(this).val());
   });
});
```

#### Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ViewName(MyModel model)
{
   return View(model);
}
```

When your `HttpPost` action for this view hits you can actually see the value of property in debugger.

This can also be done via ajax but this will save an extra call to your code and writing some code for same. If you really want to do this with ajax then please drop a comment.
Hope it helps :)

Comment: I am already using HttpPost for some other things , I can add them to this HttpPost?

Comment: and what about , e.g. if the year is 2012 , I want to comment something . How can I access that drop down from the controller?

Comment: What ever value you select will update the hidden field when drop down's change event fires (through jquery) and your model will have the value for every property if they are present in view. It is as simple as that. What is the problem then?

Comment: I also cannot use the @model as I am passing an IList of models to my view , so I guess I would have to use ajax , I don't want to bind this drop-down box to the model.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the fields are in the form you can access them using the request. They will not be bound to any model, via MVC, but the values will be present for the taking. Use the `Controller.Request` property to access them.